# Spring Boot application with File Change Listener cannot initiate repository service

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, nullpointerexception, filesystemwatcher

**Introduction**
In my spring boot application, I need a feature to read files from a monitored directory with a listener on it, then parse/upload into postgresql database once it finds a file.
Client will upload files into this directory daily, and the application should parse and insert into DB.

**The problem**
I get nullpointer exception on the service that saves into database.
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "my.app.service.CcFileService.saveCcFile(my.app.model.CcFile)" because "this.ccFileService" is null`

**Code structure**
The application class structure is as the following,

- Classes 1 and 2 are for monitoring directory for new files.
- Classes 3 and 4 are for processing the read file then parsing it then inserting it into database.
- Classes 5 and 6 are the service interface and its implementation that handle the model Entity class of the file object.

**The Code**

**1. FileWatcherConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class FileWatcherConfig 
{

    public FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher()
    {

        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher( true, Duration.ofMillis( 2000L ) , Duration.ofMillis( 1000L ) ) ;
        
        fileSystemWatcher.addSourceDirectory( new File("C://TMS//inputs//") ) ;
        
        fileSystemWatcher.addListener( new MyFileChangeListener() ) ;
        
        fileSystemWatcher.start() ;
        
        System.out.println( "started fileSystemWatcher" ) ;
        
        return fileSystemWatcher ;
    }
```

**2. MyFileChangeListener.java**

```
public class MyFileChangeListener implements FileChangeListener
{
    @Override
    public void onChange( Set< ChangedFiles > changeSet )
    {
        
        String mainPath = changeSet.iterator().next().getSourceDirectory().toString() ;
        
        for( ChangedFiles cfiles : changeSet )
        {
            for( ChangedFile cfile: cfiles.getFiles() )
            {
                if(     //cfile.getType().equals(Type.MODIFY) || 
                        cfile.getType().equals(Type.ADD) //|| 
                        //cfile.getType().equals(Type.DELETE) ) 
                        && !isLocked( cfile.getFile().toPath() ) )
                {
                    
                    String filePath = cfile.getFile().getAbsolutePath() ;
                    
                    ProcessFile processFile = new ProcessFile() ;
                    
                    System.out.println( "processing the file " ) ;
                    processFile.analyzeFile( filePath , mainPath ) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**3. ProcessFile.java**

```
public class ProcessFile
{
    private String fileName = "" ;
    
    
    public void analyzeFile( String filePath , String mainPath )
    {
        String[] pathArray = this.splitPath( filePath ) ;
        
        fileName = filePath.substring( filePath.lastIndexOf( "\\" ) + 1 ) ;
        
        switch ( fileName )
        {
          case "CCFile.LOG" :
              
              ProcessCcfile procCcfile = new ProcessCcfile() ;
              
              procCcfile.parseFile( filePath , fileName , mainPath ) ;
              
              break ;
```

**4. ProcessCCFile.java**

```
//@ApplicationScope
//@ApplicationScope
//@ControllerAdvice
//@PersistenceContext
//@Component
//@Configuration
//@Configurable
//@ApplicationScope
//@Controller
public class ProcessCcFile
{
    
    @Autowired
    private CcfileService ccfileService ;   <== //this remains null( the problem )

    Ccfile ccfileTxn = new Ccfile( 1 , 2 , "a" , "a" , "a" , "a" , 3 , "a" , "a" , 4 , "a" , "a" , "a" , "a" , true ) ;


    public void parseFile( String filePath , String fileName , String mainPath )
    {
        BufferedReader reader;

        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( filePath ) ) ;
            
            String line = reader.readLine() ;
            
            int count1 = 0 ;
            
            while( line != null )
            {   
                // read next line
                line = reader.readLine() ;
                
                // parse logic here then send to entity repo class
                
                
            }

            reader.close() ;
            

                saveFile() ;
        
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace() ;
        }
    }
    
    
    public void saveFile()
    {
        try
        {       
            ccfileService.saveCcfile( ccfileTxn ) ;   <== //and here the application fails
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace() ;
        }
    }
}
```

**5. CcfileService.java**

```
public interface CcfileService
{

    void saveCcfile( @Valid Ccfile ccfile ) ;
}
```

**6. CcfileServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class CcFileServiceImpl implements CcFileService
{
    
    @Autowired
    private CcfileRepository ccfileRepo ;
    
    
    @Override
    public void saveCcfile( @Valid Ccfile ccfile )
    {
    
        ccfileRepo.save( ccfile ) ;
    }
    
}
```

**Note,** if I make the call "ccfileService.saveCcfile( ccfileTxn ) ;" from the controller classes( which are were the web pages are handled ), then service runs fine and inserts into database.
I believe as I read and tried, the issue lies with the spring boot context not having this service registered in its context.

Appreciate your help, as this issue has taken me a good while and still not solved, also please note this is my first spring boot application.

Thank you

I tried to play with annotations in different classes and methods to no avail, I fail to see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You inject the `CcfileService` object into the `ProcessCcFile.class`. Therefore, your `ProcessCcFile.class` must be managed by Spring. Try adding the `@Component` annotation to this class.

Comment: Thank you Zeng Feng, I did so and tested it now. I get same exact result unfortunately.

Comment: I have to add a note though, since in my code I instantiate the object with its fields, it inserts into db from the ProcessCcFile.class using the service that fails! But this is only done for one time when starting up the application, after that, the very same call fails while application is running.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my issue for the sake if anyone is facing this issue.

The solution I got was from coderanch at the following link https://coderanch.com/t/773360/frameworks/File-Watcher-Spring-Boot